# Convert object to struct with generics

Tags: c#, generics, struct

I'm looking for a way to convert an object to one of several different types of structs.  I need structs because I need it to be non-nullable.  I'm not sure how to go about this, but this is what I've tried so far and it doesn't work because:
 "Object must implement IConvertible." <- trying Convert.ChangeType

```
public class Something
{
    private object[] things;

    public Something()
    {
        //I don't know at compile time if this will
        //be an array of ThingA's or ThingB's
        things = new object[1];

        things[0] = new ThingA();
        ThingA[] thingsArrayA = GetArrayofThings<ThingA>();

        things[0] = new ThingB();
        ThingB[] thingsArrayB = GetArrayofThings<ThingB>();
    }

    public TData[] GetArrayofThings<TData>() where TData : struct
    {
        return (TData[])Convert.ChangeType(things, typeof(TData[]));
    }
}

[Serializable]
public struct ThingA
{
    //...
}

[Serializable]
public struct ThingB
{
    //...
}
```

This is the working implementation thanks to Serg's answer:

```
    public TData[] GetArrayofThings<TData>() where TData: struct
    {
        return things.OfType<TData>().ToArray<TData>();
    }
```

I'm still curious about any penalties for .ToArray() because this is data which will be sent to a stream object, and there could be a lot of it.

Comment: Why do you need it to be non-nullable? In what context? This seems like a lot of work for no apparent reason (but I could be blind).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Why would you need objects to be non-nullable? Besides, I don't think you fully understand what you're trying to do here. You can't just convert an object to a struct on the fly. You need to define a struct and some form of conversion between your classes and the struct, either a method or a user defined conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that a few LINQ queries will suffice.

```
//getting only ThingA from mixed array
IEnumerable<ThingA> thingsA = things.OfType<ThingsA>()
//we know type of thins inside array, so we just need type conversion
IEnumerable<ThingB> thingsB = things.Cast<ThingB>()
```

Don't use `Convert`, it's for real *conversion* (e.g, `string` to `int`), and what you have is *type casting*.

Comment: This is getting me closer. In order to use the IEnumerable<ThingA> as a non-nullable parameter for a stream object, I need to do something like this:

 thingsA.ToArray<ThingA>();

will this incurr much overhead?

Answer (score 0):

`ChangeType` method signature exposes two parameters, the first: `value` must be an object which implements IConvertible interface. In your example `things` is an `object` array and doesn't implement that interface. 
You should design your GetArrayOfThings method in a different way like this:

> public TData[] GetArrayofThings() where TObject:IConvertible, TData: struct